# Is there a way to install Firefox add-ons in Chrome?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser-addons, ietab

### in brief

Some Firefox add-ons (e.g., [Smart Bookmarks Bar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/smart-bookmarks-bar/)) are not available as extensions for Chrome. Is there a way to install Firefox add-ons in Chrome or to install them in one of the Firefox-tab extensions?

### full details

Is there a Chrome addon to open a new tab as Firefox tab (similar to IE Tab addon but for Firefox)?
I'm looking for an addon for Chrome which functions similar to IE Tab, but it opens Firefox in a new tab inside Chrome. Any suggestion for me? Thank you!

The reason I'm looking for this addon is as followed. There's lots of addon in Firefox that are still not available in Chrome - the typical one is the smart bookmark toolbar and download helper.

Answer (score 1):

The [Mozilla Gecko Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/icoloanbecehinobmflpeglknkplbfbm) extension lets you open a page with the Gecko rendering engine in Chrome. (Of course, you need to have a Mozilla browser installed for it to work.)

The same dev also made the [IE Tab Multi](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fnfnbeppfinmnjnjhedifcfllpcfgeea) extension with the same interface and options.

Comment: the `Gecko Tab` is great but I'm looking for Firefox addons used from Chrome. Thank you anyway

Comment: Your best bet is to check [Userscripts](http://userscripts.org/) for something that simulates the add-on that you want. Most scripts there have versions for most browsers.

Comment: Of course, it is also possible to make Firefox extensions compatible with other browsers using the [WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) API.